# Get and remove query string with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, get

I'm looking for a SQL function that can get query string in the sense, URL is stored on a variable.

Actually, I need to create a trigger that will update the column containing url and encode the particular query string of the url, so to encode that particular query string, first I need to extract the query string value.

Lets say

```
@url = 'mypage.php?name=This is test&address=Test Address&phone=+9779854125896'
```

Then, I need a SQL function like

```
select getURLparams('name', @url)
```

that should return

```
This is test
```

And, how to delete particular query string, so I could append the updated one.

I am on SQL Sever 2008 R2.

Comment: I understand what you need but what is the problem you have?

Comment: Actually, I need to create a trigger that will update the column containing url and encode the particular parameter of the url, so to encode that particular param, first I need to extract the parameter value

Comment: Parsing URLs is really not a good job to be attempting with T-SQL. A CLR function with access to .NET framework may make it doable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try below query which returns querystring value with querystring name as parameter:

```
declare @url nvarchar(max) = 'mypage.php?name=This is test&address=Test Address&phone=+9779854125896'

declare @param nvarchar(max)='phone'

SELECT 
    (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('&', v)>0 THEN SUBSTRING(v, 0, CHARINDEX('&', v))
    ELSE V END)
FROM(
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@url, CHARINDEX(@param+'=', @url)+LEN(@param)+1, len(@url)) v
    WHERE CHARINDEX('&'+@param+'=', REPLACE(@url, '?', '&'))>0
)x
```

For changing the value of an existing querystring, please try:

```
declare @url nvarchar(max) = 'mypage.php?name=This is test&address=Test Address&phone=+9779854125896'

declare @param nvarchar(max)='name'
declare @NewValu nvarchar(max)='Test'


SELECT 
    REPLACE(@url, Ch+vv, Ch+@NewValu)
FROM(
    SELECT  
        (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('&', v)>0 then SUBSTRING(v, 0, CHARINDEX('&', v))
        ELSE V END) vv,
        (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('?'+@param+'=', @url)>0 
                    THEN '?'+@param+'='
                    ELSE '&'+@param+'=' END) Ch
    FROM(
        SELECT SUBSTRING(@url, CHARINDEX(@param+'=', @url)+LEN(@param)+1, len(@url)) v
        WHERE CHARINDEX('&'+@param+'=', REPLACE(@url, '?', '&'))>0
    )x
)xx
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked, Is there any way to remove a particular parameter ? So, I could append the updated param

Comment: You mean to assign new value for a particular querystring?

Comment: yeah ... I was thinking to remove particular param and assign again... Assigning would not be a problem ... I am finding difficulty on removing

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a CLR function that uses Regex. 
Read [SQL Server: Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @url as varchar(800)
set @url = 'mypage.php?name=This is test&address=Test Address&phone=+9779854125896'
declare @name as varchar(800)
set @name='name'

select SUBSTRING(@url,CHARINDEX(@name,@url,1)+len(@name)+1,
            convert(int,CHARINDEX('&',@url,1))-convert(int,CHARINDEX(@name,@url,1)+len(@name))-1)
```

Comment: While assigning value `'phone'` in param `@name` it's giving exception.

Comment: It will, i have taken many assumption. I am working out to cut most of it.